# cancan how can we create roles dropdown in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, cancan, roles

I am using cancan for role management in my app. I have different roles in my app like Super Admin, Admin, developer, tester. How can I display roles dropdown from Roles array without including Super Admin and Admin. Please look at my code

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   Roles = [:super_admin, :admin, :developer, :tester]
end
```

I need a select box containing developer and tester, and tried to create a array using following code but null item is getting in dropdown.

```
User::Roles.map{|r| 
  next if %w(super_admin admin).include?(r.to_s)
  r.to_s.humanize
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick one-liner:

```
(User::Roles - [:super_admin, :admin]).map { |r| r.to_s.humanize }
```

Comment: I don't think your first snippet will work, if you call next in a map block, you get a nil in the resulting array

Comment: @Slicepan you're right. Was working with a modified array that only had last two options. Missed out `compact`. I much prefer the simple one-liner anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
roles = User::Roles.dup
roles.delete :super_admin
roles.delete :admin
```

The roles array will have all roles except super_admin and admin

[EDIT]

Actually I think this way is better

```
ADMIN_ROLES = [:admin, :super_admin]

roles = User::Roles.select {|r| !ADMIN_ROLES.include? r}
```